# RangetoHTML- Select only certain columns

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook, automation

I have a RangetoHTML code from RonDeBruin, but I only want columns A, B, C, I, P, T, AE, and AF to be shown. I'm not sure where I would set the range as I am not extremely familiar with VBA. The table will be presented in the body of the email that VBA is producing, through Outlook.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: you can set up a "display" layer on a separate tab that only has what you want to display via formulas, then pass that as the range.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a  union of the columns in?

```
Sub test() 
    Dim rng As Range, s As String
    With ActiveSheet
       Set rng = Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("B"), .Columns("C"), .Columns("I"), .Columns("P"), .Columns("T"), .Columns("AE"), .Columns("AF"))
       s = RangetoHTML(rng)
       Debug.Print s
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this method?